# Removing specific item from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm adding some items to localStorage, using jQuery/JS, which is all fine but in trying to remove a specific item within the array (if it's the same item) is proving difficult.

In my console logs (for testing) it seems to clear the [Object] but it's not updating the key. Perhaps my hierarchy is wrong... any ideas?

```
//
function addToStorage(elem, name) {

    localData = localStorage.getItem(name + 'Storage');
    var typefaces;

    if (localData == 'null' || !localData) {
        typefaces = [];
    } else {
       typefaces = JSON.parse(localData);
    }

    typefaceID = elem.find('input').val();
    typefaceName = elem.find('input').attr('data-name');
    typefacePrice = elem.find('input').attr('data-price');
    typefaceQty = 1;

    $.each(typefaces, function(index, value) {
        if (value !== null) {
            if (value.id == typefaceID) {
                if (name == 'drf') {
                    //console.log(index);
                    //console.log(typefaces);
                    typefaces.splice(index, 1);
                    //console.log(typefaces);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    typefaces.push({
        'id': typefaceID,
        'name': typefaceName,
        'price': typefacePrice,
        'qty': typefaceQty
    });

    localStorage.setItem(name + 'Storage', JSON.stringify(typefaces));

}

//
$(document).on('click', 'summary.cart td.font', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addTo = $(this);
    addTo.each(function() {
        addToStorage(addTo, 'drf');
    });
});
```

This is an example of the localData once it's been added to.

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"dr-raymond-desktop-40374",
      "name":"DR-Raymond",
      "format":"Desktop (OTF)",
      "price":"15.00",
      "qty":1
   },
   {  
      "id":"dr-raymond-webfont-39949",
      "name":"DR-Raymond",
      "format":"Webfont (WOFF)",
      "price":"15.00",
      "qty":1
   }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give a format for your json localdata or any fiddle link so that it should be more explanatory?

Comment: @breakit That's it added to the original question thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "updating the key"?

Comment: @XavierJ Sorry if you see my image attachment from Chrome DevTools when inspecting the localStorage. The 'key' in this instance is the localStorage and the 'value' is the contents (localData array)

Comment: @JohnthePainter please check my answer you have an additional error in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never add/remove elements from an array while iterating over it using "foreach". Instead, try this:

```
for (index = typefaces.length - 1; index >= 0; index--){
    value = typefaces[index];
    if (value !== null) {
        if (value.id == typefaceID) {
            if (name == 'drf') {
                typefaces.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Another way to do this more elegantly is by using ES6 filter():

```
typefaces = typefaces.filter(value => !(value && value.id == typefaceID && name == "drf"));
```

Also, you are comparing `localData` to the literal string `'null'` which is kind of pointless. Your second condition - `if (!localData)` is enough in this case, and will handle it properly.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's still not removing it from the localStorage. If I click it once it adds it to the localStorage but if I click it again, to remove, it doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? It seems your code will always push a new item in the place of the one deleted.

Comment: Yes I have JUST worked that out haha! I don't want it to push the one that's been deleted, obviously.

Comment: I tried putting the push before the for loop but it always seems to return an empty array.

Comment: It seems to me you are trying to acheive somekind of "toggle" behavior. You named this function "addToStorage". Are you trying to do something other than adding an element to the storage?

Comment: Yes, as described in the original question, it is a kind of 'toggle'. The 'addToStorage' is perhaps slightly badly named but when they click the item to add... if they click the item that is already added then yes it should remove it from the localStorage.

Comment: I think that's happening with mine is that it's checking the items then pushing it... whereas it should push it then check it (but then it would never add it) so there needs to be a way that it checks if it's in the array... if it is then it removes it otherwise push it to array.

Comment: You can simply use the for-loop implementation I suggested above then. Initialize a boolean to `found = false;` before the `for` loop, and assign `found = true;` instead of splicing it. Now you have a boolean which indicates if this element is already in the array. Use it in an `if` statement to acheive what you're looking for

Comment: Another way to get this boolean is using filter() again: `found = typefaces.filter(value => (value && value.id == typefaceID && name == "drf")).length > 0`;

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Shouldn't I splice it if it does exist, though?

Comment: if (found) { splice it } else { push it }

Comment: I gave you the 50 points and accepted answer as you mentioned the if found implementation which after some testing this was the way that worked! Thank you and thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your splice method usage. Note that, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=example) `splice` modifies the array in place and returns a new array containing the elements that have been removed. So when using a loop and trying to remove the some elements, splice will make shifting of elements. This is because iterating incrementally through the array, when you splice it, the array is modified in place, so the items are "shifted" and you end up skipping the iteration of some. Looping backwards fixes this because you're not looping in the direction you're splicing.

### Solution 1

Loop backwards while splicing.

```
for(var i = typefaces.length; i--;)
{
            if (typefaces[i] !== null) 
            {

                if (typefaces[i] == typefaceID) 
                {
                        typefaces.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
 }
```

Working bin link [here](https://jsbin.com/bohoguf/edit?html,js,output).

### Solution 2

Its usually faster to generate a new array instead of modifying the existing one. So, your code will look like

```
ty = [];
   $.each(typefaces, function(index, value) {
        if (value !== null) {

            if (value.id != typefaceID) {
                    ty.push(value);
            }
        }
    });
  typefaces = ty;
```

Working bin link is [here](https://jsbin.com/paqexalepa/edit?html,js,console,output).
After that there is no problem found in  getting and setting your localStorage.

Comment: After doing this If you face any problem regarding localStorage ping me here.

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional error in your code, you write

```
if (value !== null) {
    if (value.id == typefaceID) {
        // name will always have the value drf 
        // since you pass it in your function
        // when you call it addToStorage(addTo, 'drf');
        if (name == 'drf') {
            typefaces.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

when it should be

```
if (value !== null) {
    if (value.id == typefaceID) {
        // here the comparison should be between value.name and name
        if (value.name == name) {
            typefaces.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

which can be also written

```
if (value !== null) {
    if (value.id == typefaceID && value.name == name) {
            typefaces.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are mutating the array by splicing it. The only localstorage items that are being re written are the ones that are left in the array.

So delete the item from the storage when you splice an object from the array.

```
$.each(typefaces, function(index, value) {
        if (value !== null) {
            if (value.id == typefaceID) {
                if (name == 'drf') {
                    //console.log(index);
                    //console.log(typefaces);
                    var removedTypeFace = typefaces.splice(index, 1);
                    //console.log(typefaces);

                    if(removedTypeFace) {
                        localStorage.removeItem(removedTypeFace.name + 'Storage');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't 'localStorage.removeItem()' only remove the entire key and not the splice from the key?

Comment: @JohnthePainter You will have to both, removing it from the array using `splice` and then removing that property from the local storage as well.

Comment: The splice makes sense but is `localStorage.removeItem(removedTypeFace.name + 'Storage');` the correct thing to remove that property from local storage?

Answer (score -1):

OK.  You're going to kick yourself.  The first time you pull from localStorage, the `getItem` method DOES return a `null` value, but you're trying to compare it to a *string* (`'null'`, in quotes).  Fail.  I changed `localData == 'null'` to `localData == null`.

The second part of the expression tries to see the value returned from `getItem` is actually defined, which is good.  I changed that to be more explicit, by way of `typeof`.

Explicit variable declarations help, too.

```js
function addToStorage(elem, name) {

    var localData = localStorage.getItem(name + 'Storage');
    var typefaces;

    if (localData == null || typeof(localData) == 'undefined') {
        typefaces = [];
    } else {
       typefaces = JSON.parse(localData);
    }

    var typefaceID = elem.find('input').val();
    var typefaceName = elem.find('input').attr('data-name');
    var typefacePrice = elem.find('input').attr('data-price');
    var typefaceQty = 1;

    $.each(typefaces, function(index, value) {
        if (value !== null) {
            if (value.id == typefaceID) {
                if (name == 'drf') {
                    //console.log(index);
                    //console.log(typefaces);
                    typefaces.splice(index, 1);
                    //console.log(typefaces);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    typefaces.push({
        'id': typefaceID,
        'name': typefaceName,
        'price': typefacePrice,
        'qty': typefaceQty
    });

    localStorage.setItem(name + 'Storage', JSON.stringify(typefaces));

}

//
jQuery(document).on('click', 'summary.cart td.font', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addTo = $(this);
    addTo.each(function() {
        addToStorage(addTo, 'drf');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<summary class='cart'><table><tr>
<td class='font' >Click Here for Item 1
<input data-name='abc' data-price='2.00' value="Item 1" /></td></tr>
<tr>
<td class='font' >Click Here for Item 2
<input data-name='def' data-price='4.00' value="Item 2" /></td></tr></table>
</summary>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! This doesn't seem to remove the item from the localStorage though? :(

Comment: It seems to remove it fine from the array (if I console.log the array before and after the removal it shows it changing from [Object] to [] BUT in it still seems to exist in the localStorage). Maybe my line `localStorage.setItem(name + 'Storage', JSON.stringify(typefaces));` isn't doing what I think it is...